# Solve the trignometric equation $2\sin (3x + \pi/4) =\sqrt{1+8\sin2x\cos^2x}$

Tags: trigonometry

The equation to be solved is
$$2\sin (3x + \pi/4) =\sqrt{1+8\sin2x\cdot\cos^2x}.
$$

I tried as [image]

But I could not undertand how to proceed

Comment: In your second last step try converting the equation into a cubic equation in $\sin(2x)$

Comment: @ShreyasS and what about sin6x

Comment: $\sin{6x} = 3\sin{2x} - 4\sin^3(2x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

First of all, $$2\sin\left(3x+\dfrac\pi4\right)=\sqrt{1+8\sin2x\cos^22x}\ge0$$

So, $3x+\dfrac\pi4$ must lie $\in[0,\pi]\pmod{2\pi}$

Now use [Werner Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html), $$2\sin4x\cos2x=\sin6x+\sin2x$$